# Windows Form Application - project builds but designer doesn't recognize List<T>

Tags: c++, winforms, list

I'm developing a Windows Form Application in Visual C++ 2010.
I'm trying to use a List (System::Collections::Generic::List). Until a certain point, all was well. Then, for no particular reason that I can see, the designer started not recognizing Link^ as a type. The error message is:

"*C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 70, Column: 17 --- Unknown type 'System.Collections.Generic.List^'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built.*"

The strange thing is that the project builds and runs perfectly, the only thing causing a problem is the Designer.

here are the important(as far as i know) sections of code:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic; //I only added this line
```

---

```
private: System::Collections::Generic::List<String^>^ MyText;
//Manually added the line above
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
```

---

```
void InitializeComponent(void)
{    
    this->MyText = (gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<String^>());
    //again, added the line above
    this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
}
```

---

```
//and this is how I'm currently using the List
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    textBox1->Text = MyText->Count + " " + MyText->Capacity;
}
// textBox1->Text becomes 0 0
```

I've tried both System::Collections::Generic::List^ MyText and just List^ MyText, (since I added *using namespace System::Collections::Generic*) but it still gives me the error message.

I have commented out the bits of code with List on it, and the designer works perfectly, but when I put the code back in play the error comes back. I tried restarting Visual C++ endless times, removing the file from the project and add it again, the result is always the same: the project builds, the designer doesn't work. I am oficially out of ideas, so... any help?

*(oh, also, there is an option to just skip the error and it does show me the designer normally, most of the times, but, as the program warns when you click that option, sometimes it shows the designer with a few controls missing and chunks of code disappear from Form1.h)*

Comment: You are editing the InitializeComponent() method by hand.  That's a Really Bad Idea, that method is reserved to the designer.  Move the MyText assignment to the constructor.

Comment: Done that and, so far, it seems to be working perfectly. Funny, I've been doing that for quite some time, never had problems with that. Well, live to learn, I guess. Thank you for your help. _(If you'd like, rewrite what you said as an answer, so I can accept it.)_

Comment: @HansPassant I just realized you were not notified of my comment and so may not have seen it. If that was the case, I apologize, and my previous comment still stands